# Java: illegal start of expression

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a programar a distancia (que compagino con un trabajo que no tiene nada qué ver con programación) y tengo una duda de Java con Netbeans. Aquí el código:

```
public class PROG02_Ejer03 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     boolean casado = true;
     static final int MAXIMO = 999999;
     byte diasemana;
     short diaano;
     boolean sexo;
     long milisegundosdesde1970;
     float factura;
     long poblacionmundial;
     } // Aquí cierro el método main
    } //Aquí cierro la public class
```

En concreto me da error en la línea de:

`static final int MAXIMO = 999999;`

Netbeans me dice

> illegal start of expression

y me marca en amarillo `MAXIMO`, pero he estado buscando y no encuentro el fallo por ningún lado, es una constante y las constantes por convención se escriben en mayúscula).

La última llave, que yo entiendo que es para cerrar la public class pero Netbeans me dice

> class, interface or enum expected.

Comment: Una variable estática en Java pertenece a toda la clase, entonces no tiene sentido declararla adentro de un método. Tiene que ser declarada a nivel de la clase y después podrás usarla en el Main o en cualquier método.

Comment: Y donde esta la llave que inicia el cuerpo del metodo main?

Comment: ¿Entonces dónde puedo poner la variable static? ¿La declaro fuera del método y luego la pongo dentro? Es que tengo entendido que las constantes siempre se ponen con "static final + tipo de dato + identificador de la variable". En cuanto a la llave que inicia el método main, se me había olvidado ponerla (que en Netbeans sí la tengo puesta) pero me sigue dándo error.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es dejarla como constante, simplemente declarala fuera del main como **final int** o como **static final int**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La declaración "static " indica que es una variable accesible sin tener que instanciar una clase. En este caso estas dentro de un main de un programa principal, así que no puedes declararla estática

Comment: exacto amigo tienes la razon

Comment: Un placer ayudar.

Comment: denada aqui estamos para ayudarnos